# PHP Symfony2 Error Mapping with an old bundle

Tags: php, namespaces, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm learning Symfony2 and I use Doctrine2 as ORM.
Everything went fine except one error. In fact this error is blocking me because she happens on every page and in the CLI too.

The error is the following:

```
ErrorException: Warning: class_parents(): Class BumpMe\UserBundle\Entity\User does not exist and could not be loaded in /home/gp2mv3/www/bumpme/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php line 223
```

The User Entity was in the UserBundle but i moved it (the files) in another bundle (AppBundle). I renamed the file and the namespaces in it.
After that i removed the UserBundle without errors.

And now, after a lot of cli commands, I've it...

How can i solve this issue ?
Where does this error come from ?

Thanks.

Comment: `BumpMe\UserBundle` and `in another bundle (AppBundle)` ?! Paste the `namespace` string of User class and its exact full path

Comment: `BumpMe\AppBundle\Entity\User` I think, In fact I've just copied the file of User.php and I change the namespace in this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error !
I  forgot one declaration in `app/config/config.yml`.

If you've the same error, reread every file and you'll probably find an old unedited statement.

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    # Allows you to enter the new user entity
    user_class: MyApp\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User
    # Used to enter the new registration form
    registration:
        form:
            type: myapp_user_registrationform
```

Comment: What was that "one declaration" that you missed? Was it a specific one? or Was your config.yml malformed?

Comment: It was a declaration for an old bundle in the config file. It's not a specific declaration.

Comment: Cool, well I can't undo my downvote since answer hasn't changed, you might wanna edit it so that I can undo it :)

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error.

I had an old `/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.yml` file lurking from when I moved my user from my MainBundle to it's own UserBundle (using annotations)

Answer (score 0):

A bit outdated, but I just come across same error, so checked config.yml (which I was editing according to 'install'), and here it is, in last line: 'Acme' user load, maybe this help someone:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
```